# why the variable rate is being used without initialized? c++

Tags: c++

Case control structure

```
int tax_code;
float p_amount, sales_tax, total, rate;

printf("\t\t\t Tax code\n\n");
printf("\t\t\t 0 - 0%%\n");
printf("\t\t\t 1 - 3%%\n");
printf("\t\t\t 2 - 5%%\n");
printf("\t\t\t 3 - 7%%\n\n");

printf("Key in tax code >>");
scanf("%d", &tax_code);
printf("Key in purchase amount >>");
scanf("%f", &p_amount);

switch (tax_code)
{
case '0' :
    rate = 0.00;
    break;
case '1' :
    rate = 0.03;
    break;
case '2' :
    rate = 0.05;
case '3' :
    rate = 0.07;
}

sales_tax = p_amount * rate;
total = p_amount + sales_tax;

printf("\nPurchase amount is RM %.2f\n", p_amount);
printf("Sales tax is RM %.2f\n", sales_tax);
printf("Total amount is RM %.2f\n", total);
```

This program is required to read a purchase amount and a tax code.The prgram must then compute the sales tax and the total amount due, and print purchase amount , sales tax and total amount due.
why the program cannot run after entering the tax code and purchase amount?

Comment: It might be good form to add a `default` case in case things don't do what you expect. I observe that cases '2' and '3' don't have a break - is this intended?

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d", &tax_code);
```

The `%d` conversion format converts an integer. If "1" is typed in, `tax_code` gets set to 1.

Your `switch` statement tests `tax_code` for ***characters*** '0', '1', '2', '3', etc... instead of actual numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your error is telling you that you are trying to use the variable `rate` without initialising it. This is due to you initialising your variable within a limited `switch-case` structure.

There are two main problems here.

1. `tax_code` is an integer, and you have correctly cast it from user input with the `%d`format specifier. However, your case labels compare this integer value to a `char` (use of single quotes around the numbers) and comparison will fail even if the "number" appears the same as they are different datatypes and are represented in memory differently.
2. Your `case` labels only handle the situations where `tax_code` is either 0, 1, 2 or 3. If it is any other value then, since you have no `default:` label, `rate` will not be assigned anything and hence be uninitialised by the time you use it later.